# Can the Ansible raw ssh module be used like "expect"?

Tags: python, ansible, pexpect, pxssh

In other words, can the ansible "expect" module be used over a raw SSH connection?

I'm trying automate some simple embedded devices that do not have a full Python or even shell.  The ansible `raw` module works fine for simple commands, but I'd like to drive things in an expect-like manner.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `expect` module is [written in python](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/commands/expect.py), so no, that won't work.

Ansible does have a model for interacting with devices like network switches that similarly don't run python; you can read about that in the [How Network Automation Is Different](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/getting_started/network_differences.html). I don't think that will offer any sort of immediate solution to your problem, but it suggests a way of pursuing things if it was really important to integrate with Ansible.

It would probably be simpler to just use the actual `expect` program instead of Ansible.

Comment: Yeah, the ansible network modules seem to be closer to what I need.  They do have basic expect-like functions.  But they seem to be Network OS specific. Hmm.

Answer (score 2):

With **Ansible 2.7** and up, you can use the cli_command module. It's kind of like 'expect' and it does not need python on the target.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/cli_command_module.html

```
- name: multiple prompt, multiple answer (mandatory check for all prompts)
  cli_command:
    command: "copy sftp sftp://user@host//user/test.img"
    check_all: True
    prompt:
      - "Confirm download operation"
      - "Password"
      - "Do you want to change that to the standby image"
    answer:
      - 'y'
      - <password>
      - 'y'
```